# Can we recover a reduced finite type $k$-scheme from its set of closed points, if $k$ is not algebraically closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $k$ be a field, which is not algebraically closed. For a $k$-scheme, let us denote by $X_0$ the set of all closed points of $X$. Let $X$ be a reduced finite type $k$-scheme. Can we recover $X$ from $X_0$? If $X$ is a smooth projective $k$-scheme, can we recover $X$ form $X_0$?

Comment: What information do you know about $X_0$... is it just a set? Then all you know is the cardinality of $X_0$, which is (for infinite fields at least) that of $k$ so you know little. However, it doesn’t sound outlandish that a morphism of reduced $k$-schemes of finite type $X \rightarrow Y$ which is a bijection on the sets of closed points is an isomorphism.

Comment: @Mindlack Can you give a reference for the last line of your comment, if k is not algebraically closed?

Comment: Oops, that statement was too reckless a guess. It's not very hard to use constructibility to show that the map must be a bijection, but it's not easy to conclude afterwards in general. If you consider instead morphisms $Y \rightarrow X$ (because $X$ is locally normal) in characteristic zero, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73321/isomorphism-between-varieties-of-char-0/73348#73348 should prove the claim.

Comment: @Mindlack: no, your assertion is false. Consider the obvious map from the cuspidal cubic to the line - this is a bijection on closed points which is not an isomorphism. As to the OP, we really need a bit more information than the set of all closed points - if it's just a set with no structure, then its only invariant is cardinality, and for an infinite field all this gives us is whether $X$ is zero-dimensional or not. This isn't interesting - do you perhaps mean something more or something else?